# in Mysql same Id with different column values show side by side using mysql query

Tags: mysql

actually, I am getting results by using MySQL query

```
id    title product_id  name    value
974   test  337         Color   BLUE
974   test  337         Size    XL
```

I want to like this below using MySQL query

```
id    title product_id  Color  Size
974   test  337         BLUE   XL
```

is it possible to write a query to merge two rows as a single row by using id?

my query is like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.title, i.product_id, a.name, av.value from inventories as i 
            left JOIN products as p on i.product_id = p.id 
            left JOIN attribute_inventory as ai on ai.inventory_id = i.id 
            left JOIN attribute_values as av on av.id = ai.attribute_value_id
            left JOIN attributes as a on a.id = ai.attribute_id
            WHERE i.id = 974
```

Comment: Maybe, if you show us table structure, sample data and actual query you are using and talking about.

Comment: edited, plz check once.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is PIVOT. Search - there is a lot of techniques.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

I got answer my question

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.title,
                max(case when (a.name='Color') then av.value end) as 'Color',
                max(case when (a.name='Size') then av.value end) as 'Size'
                from inventories as i 
                left JOIN attribute_inventory as ai on ai.inventory_id = i.id 
                left JOIN attribute_values as av on av.id = ai.attribute_value_id
                left JOIN attributes as a on a.id = ai.attribute_id
                WHERE i.id = 974
                group by i.id
```